# Android: Sending SensorData to TextView in MVVM with LiveData

Tags: java, android, mvvm, sensors, android-livedata

**EDIT:**
Based on recommendation of mohammed, I have watched Mitchs video tutorial several times and I think I understand the basic structure of LiveData better now. I tried to adapt his method step by step to my described issue, but I am still struggling and maybe I now have more fundamental questions than before.

My basic questions are:

If you have sensor data of more than a dozen signal objects (i.e. acceleration x/y/z, gyroscope data, ambient pressure, temperature and so on): What is the best way to provide all that data through LiveData to View objects? I suspect to observe every single object with separate LiveData assignments is not the best way and it is better to use a List object for example.

If you would use a List object, how can values of objects within the list be updated frequently within onSensorChanged? My attempt in using .add in each onSensorChanged event obviously results in an array of multiple signal objects instead of keeping one updated. The recommendations I found on different SO posts don't show a reasonable way for that.

If you are going with Mitchs example of using LiveData and you are not interested in showing them as a complete list with RecyclerView: How can you access one member of that list to provide its value to a TextView?

I try to set up my MVVM pattern for several weeks now, but I don't come to a solution for displaying a simple acceleration sensor value from model in TextView. :-( A breaktrough moment would highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

===========================================================================

I am currently struggling in displaying an acceleration value in a TextView within a Fragment by using LiveData in MVVM pattern.
Data-binding is activated in Gradle and dependencies are set. I am able to display a countertimer value which is directly observed as MutableLiveData, but I am not able to display other values of a list object.

Maybe my design is a bit overcomplicated, but I will try to explain step by tep:

Within my Model package, MSignal.class defines the properties for sensor signal values which can be used for signal objects in subclasses

```
public class MSignal extends Service {
    //Define signal attributes for objects in subclasses
    protected String signalName = "";
    protected String signalLongName = "";
    protected float signalActValue = 0;
    protected long signalActTime = 0;
    protected String signalUnit = "";
    protected String signalDescription = "";
    private double signalFrequency = 0;
    private double signalTimestep = 0;

    public MSignal() {
    }

...
```

The subclass MSignalSensors is receiving SensorEvents on a separate thread and stores the value within object accXSensRaw and puts it into ArrayList signalSensorsList. Then signalSensorsList is sent to a central singleton class MSignalDatabase by using Setter.

```
//Instance of MSignalDatabase singleton data service
MSignalDatabase mSignalDatabase = MSignalDatabase.getInstance();


List<MSignal> signalSensorsList = new ArrayList<MSignal>();

//signal objects
MSignal accXSensRaw = new MSignal();


...

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        accXSensRaw.signalActValue = event.values[0];
        signalSensorsList.add(accXSensRaw);
    SignalDatabase.setSignalSensor(signalSensorsList);
...
```

MSignalDatabase extends BaseObservable. Besides objects signalSensor list, which is provided by MSignalSensors, is another object „measureCounterTime“. This object is created in a separate class MSignalTime on a separate thread and delivers the central measure counter time starting with 0 seconds and a timestep of 100 milliseconds.

```
public class MSignalDatabase extends BaseObservable {
    //define singleton data service
    private static final MSignalDatabase signalSingletonInstance = new MSignalDatabase();

    public static MSignalDatabase getInstance(){
        return signalSingletonInstance;
    }

    public MSignalDatabase() {}

...

// CENTRAL TIMESTAMP DATA
private float measureCounterTime; // Measurement counter in ms when measurement is started. Counting upwards with Constant.DATALOGGING_TIMESTEP_MILLIS
public float getMeasureCounterTime() { return measureCounterTime; }
public void setMeasureCounterTime(float measureCounterTime) { this.measureCounterTime = measureCounterTime; }


// SENSOR DATA (ARRAYLIST)
private List<MSignal> signalSensor;
public List<MSignal> getSignalSensor() { return signalSensor; }
public void setSignalSensor(List<MSignal> signalSensor) { this.signalSensor = signalSensor; }
```

Object measureCounterTime is refreshed onTick in ViewModel class „VMViewModel“ based on a custom CountUpTimer (based on CountDownTimer) to refresh UI data with a specific timestep of 1000 milliseconds and then provided to MutableLiveData counterTimestepRefreshUI which can be accessed by getCounterTimestepRefreshUI.

**Here is the first thing where I struggle: I also want to set MutableLiveData signalData in the same way, but I don’t know how to cast List signalSensor to MutableLiveData<List> (if this is the right form to use list with LiveData) ==> how can that be done?**

```
public class VMViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {

private MSignalDatabase mSignalDatabase = MSignalDatabase.getInstance();

private MutableLiveData<String> counterTimestepRefreshUI;
public LiveData<String> getCounterTimestepRefreshUI() {
    if(counterTimestepRefreshUI == null){
        counterTimestepRefreshUI = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    }
    return counterTimestepRefreshUI;
}

private MutableLiveData<List<MSignal>> signalData;
public LiveData<List<MSignal>> getSignalData() {
    return signalData;
}


private CountUpTimer counterUIRefreshRate = new CountUpTimer(Constant.UI_REFRESHRATE_MILLIS) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long elapsedTime) {
            float measureCounterTimeInt = mSignalDatabase.getMeasureCounterTime();
            counterTimestepRefreshUI.setValue(String.valueOf(measureCounterTimeInt));

            //Casting signalSensor to signalData not working
            signalData = mSignalDatabase.getSignalSensor();

    }
};
```

In View I have created a Fragment „VFragmentValues with a simple TextView“. I want to set observer method on LiveData object counterTimestepRefreshUI to get the constant defined UI refresh rate.

**Here is my second and major trouble: Instead of sending the counterTimestepRefreshUI value to TextView in onChanged, I want to send accXSignalRaw.signalActValue to TextView. How can I directly access that variable through list object and communicate it to TextView?**

```
public class VFragmentValues extends Fragment {
    public VFragmentValues() {
        super(R.layout.fragment_values);
    }

    private VMViewModel viewModel;
    private FragmentValuesBinding fragmentValuesBinding;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentValuesBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_values, container, false);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(VMViewModel.class);
        fragmentValuesBinding.setLifecycleOwner(getActivity());
        View view = fragmentValuesBinding.getRoot();
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final Observer<String> counterTimestepRefreshUI = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String counterTimestepRefreshUI) {
                //This line is working and counterTime is displayed and updated in TextView within Fragment
                fragmentValuesBinding.textViewSensor.setText(counterTimestepRefreshUI);

            //This one instead is not working. How can I access accXSensRaw.signalActValue here?  
                LiveData<List<MSignal>> sensorDataUI = viewModel.getSignalData();
                fragmentValuesBinding.textViewSensor.setText(sensorDataUI.???????);

            }
        };
        viewModel.getCounterTimestepRefreshUI().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), counterTimestepRefreshUI);
    }
```

I have to say that it is still hard for me to follow the concept of LiveData observer between View, ViewModel and Model database, especially how to prepare and where to cast data/objects in the right way.

At the end I hope you can follow my thoughts, concept and troubles and you can give me some advice on how to handle that problem. I am thankful for any info and looking forward to your answers.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: I think [mitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijXjCtCXcN4/) did a great job of explaining the concept of MVVM and the its components with a pretty good example. It will definitely help you understand how it works all together.

Comment: @mohammedahmedahmed: Thank you for the link to the video. I already have seen it, but watched it for a second time with more focus. Like you mentioned the video includes a lot of guidelines for my issue. I will try to translate the NicePlaces >> RecyclerView into my case of AccXSensRaw >> TextView. I guess my misunderstanding is within the use of onChanged method on observing CounterTimeSignal instead of List<MSignal> which I have to update with UI refreshrate directly in MSignalDatabase or a separate repository.